# Difference between ASP.NET Performance Counters

Tags: asp.net, performancecounter, loadrunner

I am doing some performance/load testing on an enterprise ASP.NET application using LoadRunner. LoadRunner allows me to monitor some performance counters on the remote machine but I'm a little confused on the differences between them. Some have the ASP.NET version number and some dont. Is there a difference?

There seem to be several objects I can look at: ASP.NET Applications, ASP.NET Apps v2.0.50727, ASP.NET v2.0.50727. The counters I'm interested in are: Requests in Application Queue vs. Requests Queued, and Requests Executing.

I've read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647791.aspx#scalenetchapt15_topic12) article but it doesn't describe the difference between an Object with or without a version number. Is there a difference?

EDIT:
I've found part of my answer in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a99txfy5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#aspnet_performance_counters) article

> Performance counters enable you to monitor the operation of ASP.NET from the Windows Performance console. Each version of the .NET Framework installs a separate set of performance counter objects to monitor ASP.NET applications and to monitor ASP.NET as a whole. These objects use the naming conventions "ASP.NET Apps v.X.X.XXXX.X" and "ASP.NET v.X.X.XXXX.X", respectively, where v.X.X.XXXX.X denotes the ASP.NET version.
>
> In addition, the .NET Framework also installs ASP.NET system and ASP.NET application performance counters that apply to any installed versions of ASP.NET. Although these counters are valid for all versions of ASP.NET, they always correspond to the latest installed version. If the latest version of ASP.NET is uninstalled, these counters are automatically re-associated with the latest remaining version of ASP.NET.

Knowing this, whats the difference between ASP.NET Applications\Requests in Application Queue vs. ASP.NET v2.X\Requests Queued

Answer (score 0):

Requests in Application Queue will show you the number of requests that are Queued up for a single instance of an application running under ASP.NET (i.e. for a single website or virtual application)

Requests Queued is for the (Aggregate) all request that are queuing up on the web server.

**Requests Queued:**
The number of requests waiting for service from the queue. When this number starts to increment linearly with increased client load, the Web server computer has reached the limit of concurrent requests that it can process. The default maximum for this counter is 5,000. You can change this setting in the Machine.config file.